# Using JSOUP to Parse Nested Divs

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse nested Divs using JSOUP. I can get the most outer layered div using a simple
`Elements divs=doc.getElementsByTag("div");`, however, what is the most efficient way of getting all other divs as well.

My problem is that I have a webpage which I am trying to retrieve input tags from. However, there are mulitple input tags all in different divs, and in each div, layered 3 layers down.
The only way I can think of reaching it, is by looping through each div, getting it's divs, and continuing until I come across an input tag. That isn't the most efficient, so I wanted to know if there is another better solution.

Example html:

```
<div>
     <div>
          <div>
               <input></input>
          </div>

     </div>
     <div>
          <div>
               <input></input>
          </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do "doc.getElementByTag("input")"?

Comment: If that's a regular webpage the divs can have `id` or `class` attrbutes. You can identify them with these attributes.

Comment: @SatvikVejendla that doesn't seem to work as when JSOUP first get's its document object from the url, it doesnt recognize the nested tags, so it sees no input tagged elements

Comment: @KrystianG They do have similar class attributes, which is what I also tried using, but as I mentioned JSOUP will only get the outermost div at the start, so it never sees the input tags